# How to combat Cascade in Commander

Tags: magic-the-gathering, mtg-commander

recently moved from standard and began playing Commander last weekend using two of the new 2016 sets. Mine is Breed Lethality vs opponent's Entropic Uprising. So far I've lost 5 out of 6 games, and I'm not a bad player! Once he gets the cascade going, especially with multiple recurrences using [Yidris, Maelstrom Wielder](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bYidris%2c%20Maelstrom%20Wielder%5d), I'm essentially dead.

So then, what is the best tactic to combat cascade!?!? Especially given my deck. I really don't want to break up the deck, but if I have to. Perhaps these two are just mismatched.

Restating the above question, what is the best tactic to combat cascade? (I thought this was evident already...)

Thanks & happy holidays.

Comment: "Once he gets the cascade going, especially with multiple recurrences using Yidris, Maelstrom Wielder, I'm essentially dead." I need to check a couple of details. (a) Was his deck altered with new cards? C16 only has three spells with Cascade, not counting Yidris. (b) Are you conscious of the fact Yidris only applies Cascade to the spell you originally cast from your hand, and *does not* in turn apply Cascade to the cards cast via Cascade, and playing as such? (It's a common misreading to think he applies Cascade to the first spell, then the one that card cascades out, and so on.)

Comment: Also, is it *just* you two playing each other with these decks one-on-one, or are you playing in a larger multiplayer group?

Comment: Just 2 players, using those above same decks. I don;t want to dismantle mine yet, there should be some way to make it work. I cannot imagine one deck would be made that simply cannot win against another. Thanks.

Comment: Just 2 players, using those above same decks. Neither deck has been altered yet. I cannot imagine one deck would be made that simply cannot win against another. I think your point B is where I am struggling and opponent is smearing me - wrongly. He IS applying cascade both from his hand and then repeatedly until he cannot play anything else! Essentially, he was able to cycle almost 1/3 his deck each turn!  So if he casts 2 from his hand that turn, he ONLY gets 2 cascades??? Thank, this helps immensely! Other tips to counter are good, but interpretation of the card itself is great!

Comment: Commander is about a multiplayer environment, i.e. 3-5 players, sometimes even more. The decks are not necessarily balanced for doing 1v1 from the very beginning. I've taken the opportunity to [create a question and answer about how Yidris works](http://boardgames.stackexchange.com/q/33321/5573); I've been considering doing it but you gave me the impetus and some wording to use. (I hope you don't mind.) Also, FYI, there is a separate format that adjusts Commander for 1v1 play called [Duel Commander](http://www.duelcommander.com/), with its own banlist and other rules.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are different things you can do:

1) prevent the cascade from ever triggering

2) prevent the cascade from doing anything

@ 1) in your case:

- you could kill Yidris before he can deal damage
- Prevent Yidris from gaining this ability: you could prevent any damage, e.g. with fog effects ([Fog](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bFog%5d)) or you could give yourself protection from Yidris, e.g. with [Runed Halo](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bRuned%20Halo%5d)
- prevent Yidris from ever coming into play, e.g. via [Nevermore](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bNevermore%5d)
- prevent Yidris from attacking: some very cheap options are [Pacifism](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bPacifism%5d) effects.

@ 2)

- Cascade is a triggered ability, therefore you could counter it with [Trickbind](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bTrickbind%5d) or [Stifle](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bStifle%5d).
- If you cannot counter the ability, you could make sure, that cascade can't cast the spell:
- a) make sure your opponent can only cast spells at sorcery speed (e.g. <s>Venser</s> Teferi* as suggested by DSynergy)
- b) make sure, our opponent can't cast more than one spell, e.g. [Curse of Exhaustion](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bCurse%20of%20Exhaustion%5d)

*sorry, always confuse these two, thanks to Louis

Comment: DSynergy didn't suggest Venser.

Comment: Another option is counterspells that can hit multiple spells at a time like Mindbreak trap and Double Negative (which was originally designed to deal with cascade)

Answer (score 2):

So cascade is good because it is a powerful card advantage engine. This is why Bloodbraid Elf is banned in Modern and Shardless Agent has made a tier 1 deck in Legacy.

There are a few strong counters to cascade. My favorite it Teferi, Mage of Zhalfir. Since they can only cast spells at sorcery speed, they can never cast the cascaded spell. Other spells like counterflux can counter all spells on the stack.

Considering it is commander, you will probably need a collection of cards like this to fight against cascade. However, considering the problem is the commander, honestly just packing more removal for it, such as go for the throat, swords to plowshares, flame slash, etc is your best bet